# Do Oracle databases use Java internally?

Tags: oracle, java

My question is fairly simple. Is Java used internally by Oracle in their DBMSs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.

All (standard) packages are written in PL/SQL. 
The DBMS engine itself is written in C

**Edit:**
Oracle does include a JVM which runs on the same machine as the database itself, but that is not used to run any "DBMS related" code.

It's only there to run stored procedures/functions written in Java.

Comment: Wow, did not no know about the C part. +1.

Comment: Check out their "History Timeline": http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/timeline/index.html: 1983: "Oracle releases Version 3 of its database, with server code written in the C programming language"

Comment: My guess is Java is not exists then. I think first Java came at Oracle 8i.

Comment: Oracle has [an internal JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Corporate.2Ftechnical_timeline) and many of its tools [are written in Java](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=665002).

Comment: The internal JVM is not used to run any "DBMS related" code. It's only there to run stored procedures/functions written in Java.

Comment: Just spent a good 5 minutes researching this... You're right. You'll have to edit your answer somehow so I can take my down vote back.  :)

Comment: @Nick: I added my comment as an answer ;)

Comment: Great. Vote reversed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I guess it depends on what you mean by "standard" packages.  Oracle ships a number of packages that are built in Java (anything that uses XDB, for example, including many of the XMLQuery packages, depend on the internal JVM).  These aren't "standard" in the sense of packages that most developers use frequently.  But they are "standard" in the sense that they are installed when you do a default installation of the Oracle database.